# How to restart a program in python?

Tags: python, loops

Im a student, and just started learning python a month back, so right now, I have only learnt the basics. My teacher had given me a question like this, and the problem is, I dont know how to rerun a program, suppose, after finding the area of a particular shape, I want it to loop back to printing the first statement.
Is there any way of doing that without re-running the program using the "F5" key?

```
 print "1. Triangle"
 print "2. Circle"
 print "3. Rectangle"

 shape= input("Please Select the serial number =")

 if shape==1:
     a=input("Base =")
     b=input("Height =")
     area=0.5*a*b
     print area
 if shape==2:
     a=input("Radius =")
     area=3.14*a*a
     print area
 if shape==3:
     a=input("Width")
     b=input("Length")
     area=a*b
     print area
```

Comment: Are you running it as a script or interactively?

Comment: I would suggest learning python fully, from http://www.codecademy.com

Comment: The point is not to "restart" it, but to avoid exiting it in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: [While loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) are what you're looking for.

Comment: @Dagrooms they're *trying* to learn Python.

Comment: @dimo414 I don't get it

Comment: Your question is tagged with [tag:loops]. Why don't you use one?

Comment: @Dagrooms telling someone who starts their question with 'I just started learning python' to 'learn python fully' isn't constructive.  That's what they're trying to do already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restart, just use a simple `while` loop.

```
while True:
    # Your lovely code
```

Then just put some validation at the end:

```
    again = raw_input("Play again? ")
    if again.startswith('n') or again.startswith('N'):
        break
    else: 
        continue
```